# Chi-square application

Tags: probability, chi-squared-test

I have searched about chi-square test and what I read is only about its application to genetics like Mendel's law. My data is about internet marketing where my variable is about user sessions. What I got from chi-square test I tried to apply to user sessions. I made data for observed user sessions and then for expected user sessions. I know the sum of expected and observed should be same.

1st. Question how to make expected column (user sessions): Is it by selecting  randomly, keeping their sum equal to observed sum?

2nd. Is it applicable to my data? My expected user sessions were 4000 and what
I observed was 4, so this single calculation becomes $(4-4000)^2/4000=3992$. By adding others in my outcome is like 21747!!!! But I read chi-square should be less than 1000.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the table by day:

```
day  expected observed
1     4000      4   
2     200       50
3     234       200
4     5000      289
5      333       41
6      3999      209
```

Right now I am making expected values randomly as I am not clear about expected value. And one more important thing is I have one class in my case as its user sessions. Ask me if any ambiguity about question.

Comment: Please include in one sentence what statistical question you are trying to answer, i.e. what are you trying to achieve with the chi-squared test?. You have your observed data which I assume you collect through your server. How do you generate your 'expected' user session data?

Comment: Large chi-square statistics are inevitable if the sum of observed frequencies and the sum of expected frequencies aren't equal. That certainly implies a hypothesis that fits poorly. It's customary to translate expected probabilities to expected frequencies by multiplying by the total frequency, so total frequencies match.

Comment: Please use capitalisation and punctuation as usual in formal written English. You are not texting friends or relations; you are posting in a public forum and it's not in your interests to make what you say more difficult to read.

Comment: To answer one of your questions: random guesses at expected frequencies are completely incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I do not understand what type of $\chi^2 $ test you are trying to perform. And I suspect that you don't either. There are two types of $\chi^2 $ tests:

**1- Goodness-Of-Fit**: A goodness-of-fit test is a one variable Chi-square test, with the goal of determining whether a set of frequencies or proportions is similar to and therefore “fits” with a hypothesized set of frequencies or proportions” . A Chi-square goodness-of-fit test is like to a one-sample t-test. It determines if a sample is similar to, and representative of, a population. **Catch-point:** You need to hypothesise a true distribution.

**Example:** Compare the proportions of M&M’s of each color in a given packet to the proportions that Mars (the manufacturer) claims to produce. In order to be able to carry out this test, you need to have your packet of M$M's and know the true distribution that Mars claims.

**2- Test of Independence**:
A test of independence is a two variable Chi-square test. Like any Chi-square test the data are frequencies, so there are no scores and no means or standard deviations. The goal of a two-variable Chi-square is to determine whether or not the first variable is related to—or independent of—the second variable. A two variable Chi-square test or test of independence is similar to the test for an interaction effect in ANOVA, that asks: Is the outcome in one variable related to the outcome in some other variable.

**Example:** To continue with the M&M’s example, with the independence test, you can investigate whether the colour distributions of the M&M's in two different bags differ from each other. All you need is to purchase two bags from the market and count the colour frequencies in each.

Comment: i think its the first one because at the end i want to know that if my expected user sessions are equal to observed user sessions. its only one variable and frequencies are available for each day

Comment: If that is the case, do you know what your true distribution should be?

Answer (score 0):

First, chi-square is used in all forms of research, it is very general.

Second, where ever you heard or read that the statistic should be under 1,000 - forget it. It can range from 0 to infinity. If you have large numbers and your null hypothesis is far from true, you will get large values.

Third, since you probably want a goodness of fit test, you need to figure out the expected frequencies. You do *not* just guess. One possible hypothesis is that the frequencies are uniformly distributed over the days. Then, the table would be

```
day  expected observed
1     4000      2294.33   
2     200       2294.33
3     234       2294.33
4     5000      2294.33
5      333      2294.33
6      3999     2294.33
```

and your chi-square would be 11,163.06, which would have a p value with 15 0's. You don't say what software you are using, but in `R` this could be found with

```
obs <- c(4000, 200, 234, 5000, 333, 3999)
chisq.test(obs)
```

But you may have a different null hypothesis.

It would help if you told us a lot more about the context. My post [how to ask a statistics question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help.